# Jenkins Could not find module "@angular-devkit/build-angular"

Tags: node.js, angular, jenkins, npm, jenkins-pipeline

I have a jenkins pipeline for my angular 6 project.
the pipeline fails with the error:
Could not find module "@angular-devkit/build-angular" from "/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/sbAdmin".

That library is indeed only in the DevDependency section of package.json, so i understand why it cannot be found. so to solve that, i install it (along with some more useful libs) in a previous step. Still no luck.
Looking for any tip or example of how to solve it.

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages{
      stage('Preinstall') {
        steps {
          sh 'NOVE_ENV=prod'
          sh 'npm install @angular/cli @angular/compiler-cli @angular-devkit/build-angular typescript'
        }
      }
      stage('Install') {
        steps {
          sh 'npm install'
        }
      }
      stage('Build') {
        steps {
          // sh 'npm run build'  
          sh 'npm run ng -- build --prod'
        }
      }
    }
}
```

I'm getting the error: `Could not find module "@angular-devkit/build-angular"`, even tho there is a previous successful step of installing it.
Here is the package.json:

```
{
  "name": "sb-admin",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "author": "Amir Gilboa",
  "description": "",
  "angular-cli": {},
  "engines": {
    "node": "8.9.4",
    "npm": "6.1.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve --port 4201",
    "build": "ng build --prod",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^6.1.3",
    "@angular/common": "^6.1.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "^6.1.3",
    "@angular/core": "^6.1.3",
    "@angular/forms": "^6.1.3",
    "@angular/http": "^6.1.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^6.1.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^6.1.3",
    "@angular/router": "^6.1.3",
    "@auth0/angular-jwt": "^2.0.0",
    "@ng-select/ng-select": "^2.13.0",
    "@tinymce/tinymce-angular": "^2.3.1",
    "angular2-recaptcha": "^1.1.0",
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",

    "bootstrap": "^4.1.3",


    "core-js": "^2.5.7",


    "express-jwt": "^5.3.1",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.3.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.10",
    "moment": "^2.22.2",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.21",


    "ng2-file-upload": "^1.3.0",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "^3.0.1",
    "ngx-slick": "^0.2.1",
    "ngx-spinner": "^6.1.2",
    "ngx-toastr": "^9.0.2",

    "popper.js": "^1.14.4",
    "primeicons": "^1.0.0-beta.10",
    "primeng": "^6.1.2",
    "rxjs": "^6.2.2",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.2.2",
    "tether": "^1.4.4",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.26"

  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.7.4",
    "@angular/cli": "^6.1.4",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^6.1.3",
    "@angular/language-service": "^6.1.3",
    "@types/express": "^4.16.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "^2.8.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "^2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "^10.7.1",
    "chai": "^4.1.2",
    "chai-http": "^4.0.0",
    "codelyzer": "^4.4.4",
    "concurrently": "^3.6.1",
    "jasmine-core": "^3.2.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "^4.2.1",
    "karma": "^3.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.1.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.3.0",
    "mocha": "^5.2.0",
    "nodemon": "^1.18.3",
    "protractor": "^5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "^7.0.1",
    "tslint": "^5.11.0",
    "typescript": "^2.8.4"
  }
}
```

Comment: Try change Build stage to `sh 'npm install && npm run ng -- build --prod'` and remove Preinstall and Install stages

Comment: Thanks @yong, but i get the same message: Could not find module "@angular-devkit/build-angular" from "/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/sbAdmin".

Comment: It's weird.  please show your package.json.

Comment: i have added the package.json to the question above. thank you.